# Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

Tags: php, mysql

```
$q="SELECT * FROM tbl_quevote WHERE que_id = '".$qid."' and voteby='".$uid."'";

$result = $mysqli->query($q) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo $num_rows;
```

**Error:**

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\shizin\voting.php on line 13

How to check result is empty?

Answer (score 34):

```
$num_rows = $result->num_rows;
```

Comment: +1 - For the right answer, but it helps to give more info. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php, as num_rows is part of the mysqli extension and mysql_num_rows is part of a different extension.

Answer (score 2):

`int mysql_num_rows ( resource $result )`
Retrieves the number of rows from a result set. This command is only valid for statements like `SELECT` or `SHOW` that return an actual result set. To retrieve the number of rows affected by a `INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE` query, use `mysql_affected_rows()`.